# @OneToMany relationship: "one" id not persisted

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

This is my "header" entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "documenti")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Documento implements Serializable {

    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy="testataDocumento",
        cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch=FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private Set<RigaDocumento> righe= new HashSet<RigaDocumento>();

//...
}
```

and these are the "rows":

```
@Entity
@Table(name="righe_documenti")
public class RigaDocumento implements Serializable {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Documento testataDocumento;

//...
}
```

Well I have a common situation:

```
Documento d = new Documento();
// various Documento settings
List<RigaDocumento> rows;
// creation of rows
d.setRighe( rows );
```

Then I persist **d**.

Header is persisted correctly and rows too but...

the "testataDocumento_id" field (the key to the "one" side of the relationships) in the rows record is NULL.

Do I have to do a:

```
row.setTestataDocumento(d);
```

?

Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do have to call `row.setTestataDocumento(d);` as it is the owning side of the relationship.  Ideally, you would have an `addRow()` method in Documento which would add the row to set and also set the document of the row.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to, because you have a bidirectional association, and the owner side of the association is RigaDocumento. The owner side is the side which doesn't have the `mappedBy` attribute. The other side is called the inverse side, and is ignored by JPA/Hibernate.